# Automagic with related model data

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with automagic and related model data. I have 4 models: Exercice, Ecriture, Ligne, Compte. Exercice hasmany Ecriture and Ecriture hasmany Ligne and Compte hasmany Ligne in two relation given by to different foreign keys. I want to use automagic to populate my form. So using $this->data, I give this array to the view:

```
Array

(

[Exercice] => Array

(

[id] => 1

[theme] => marchandises

)

[Ecriture] => Array

(

[0] => Array

(

[id] => 1

[exercice_id] => 1

[numero] => 1

[enonce] => Quelle est la dincee?

[Ligne] => Array

(

[0] => Array

(

[id] => 1

[ecriture_id] => 1

[compte_debit_id] => 2

[compte_credit_id] => 1

[montant_debit] => 23

[montant_credit] => 23

[libelle] => Achat de marchandises

[student_id] => 1

[CompteDebit] => Array

(

[id] => 2

[nom] => achat marchandises

)

[CompteCredit] => Array

(

[id] => 1

[nom] => caisse

)

)

)

)
```

Now if I want to access to the first level I simply use:

$this->Form->input('Ecriture.0.enonce');

And everything works fine!

But I can't access the seconde level using:

$this->Form->input('Ecriture.0.Ligne.0.libelle');

Why is that so? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, the question was actually in listbox. I changed that now. My question is why the fields relative to the second level are not populated automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

Within Controller:

```
$this->data = array(  
'Exercice' => array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', etc.),  
'Ecriture' => array(0 => array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', etc.)),  
'Ligne' => array(0 => array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', etc.)),  
)
```

As you can see, what I'm proposing is to place the data for associated models in the same level and NOT nested one within the other. So, by this approach, you can set the form elements like: `$this->Form->input('Exercice.column1');` or `$this->Form->input('Ecriture.0.column1');`

By the way, now that I think about it, you should be able to populate the `$this->data` array automatically (for the form fields) by using read(), like: `$this->data = $this->ModelName->read(null, $recordId)`. See more [here in the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data).

Comment: Actually, I'm using read and containable to acceed to all levels of the relations. But for some reason Cake populates only the fields of the first level.

Comment: Then try re-arranging the fields so that all are within a first level.